# Automapper based on dynamic conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

I have multiple classes
I am using automapper to map the classes

```
class Country
{
  public int Countryid {get;set}
  public string CountryEnglishName {get;set;}
  public string CountryArabicName {get;set;}
  public Location Location{get;set;}

}

class Location
{
  public int Locationid {get;set}
  public string LocationEnglishName {get;set;}
  public string LocationArabicName {get;set;}

}

class Customer
{

 public int Customerid {get;set}
 public string CustomerName {get;set;}
 public int LocationId
 public Location Location{get;set;}
 public string PropertyArabicName {get;set;}
 public string PropertyEnglishName{get;set;}
}
```

And  my DTO looks like below

```
class CustomerDetailsReadDTO
{
 public int Customerid {get;set}
 public string PropertyName {get;set;}
 public string CustomerName {get;set;}
 public string CountryName {get;set;}
 public string LocationName {get;set;}
}
```

If user pass API parameter as "en-US" then CountryDTO class field Country should contain with CountryEnglishName like that Location field also.

My mapping looks like below

```
class AutomapperProfile :Profile
{
CreateMap<Customer,CustomerDetailsReadDTO>
.ForMember(dest=>dest.CountryName,opt.MapFrom<CustomResolver,string>(src=>src.Location.Country.CountryEnglishName))
.ForMember(dest=>dest.LocationName,opt.MapFrom<CustomResolver,string>(src=>src.Location.LocationEnglishName))
.ForMember(dest=>dest.PropertyName,opt.MapFrom<CustomResolver,string>(src=>src.Location.PropertyNameEnglishName));
}
```

my interface and customresolver looks like below

This interface has been scoped in startup class

```
public interface ILanguage
{
string Language{get;set;}
}
```

```
public class CustomResolver:IMemberResolver<object,object,string,string>
{
private string _Lang;

public CustomResolver(ILanguage ilanguage)
{
_Lang = ilanguage;
}
public string Resolve(object source,object destination,string sourcemember,string destmember,ResoutionContext context)
{
var type = source.GetType();
switch(Type.Name)
{
case "Country":
var country =(Country)source;
return _Lang == "en-US" ? country.CountryEnglishName :country.CountryArabicName;

case "Location":
var location =(Location)source;
return _Lang == "en-US" ? location.locationEnglishName :location.locationArabicName;
}

}
}
```

Iam getting correctvalues in PropertyName after mapping.While passing ar-SA iam getting arabicpropertyname else englishpropertyname.

Here the propblem is after mapping iam getting CountryName and LocationName value as empty string .

Can we get correct values for CountryName and LocationName based on language?

Can we solve this  ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully working sample console project, that does what you want:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    class Country
    {
        public int Countryid { get; set; }
        public string CountryEnglishName { get; set; }
        public string CountryArabicName { get; set; }
    }

    class Location
    {
        public int Locationid { get; set; }
        public string LocationEnglishName { get; set; }
        public string LocationArabicName { get; set; }
        public Country Country { get; set; }
    }

    class Customer
    {
        public int Customerid { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public string PropertyArabicName { get; set; }
        public string PropertyEnglishName { get; set; }
    }

    class CustomerDetailsReadDTO
    {
        public int Customerid { get; set; }
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
    }

    class AutomapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public AutomapperProfile(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDetailsReadDTO>()
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.CountryName,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(
                        s => serviceProvider.GetService<ILanguage>().Language == "en-US"
                            ? s.Location.Country.CountryEnglishName
                            : s.Location.Country.CountryArabicName))
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.LocationName,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(
                        s => serviceProvider.GetService<ILanguage>().Language == "en-US"
                            ? s.Location.LocationEnglishName
                            : s.Location.LocationArabicName))
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.PropertyName,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(
                        s => serviceProvider.GetService<ILanguage>().Language == "en-US"
                            ? s.PropertyEnglishName
                            : s.PropertyArabicName));
        }
    }

    interface ILanguage
    {
        string Language { get; set; }
    }

    class CurrentLanguage : ILanguage
    {
        public string Language { get; set; }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddScoped<ILanguage>(p => new CurrentLanguage())
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(
                cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(t => serviceProvider.GetService(t));
                    cfg.AddProfile(new AutomapperProfile(serviceProvider));
                });
            
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            var customer = new Customer
            {
                Customerid = 1,
                CustomerName = "John",
                LocationId = 1,
                Location = new Location
                {
                    Locationid = 1,
                    LocationEnglishName = "New York",
                    LocationArabicName = "نِيويورْك",
                    Country = new Country
                    {
                        Countryid = 1,
                        CountryEnglishName = "USA",
                        CountryArabicName = "الوِلايات المُتَّحِدة الأَمْريكيّة",
                    }
                },
                PropertyArabicName = "مبني المقاطعة الملكية",
                PropertyEnglishName = "Empire State Building", 
            };

            serviceProvider.GetService<ILanguage>().Language = "en-US";
            var englishDto = mapper.Map<CustomerDetailsReadDTO>(customer);

            serviceProvider.GetService<ILanguage>().Language = "ar-SA";
            var arabicDto = mapper.Map<CustomerDetailsReadDTO>(customer);

            Debug.Assert(englishDto.CountryName == "USA");
            Debug.Assert(englishDto.LocationName == "New York");
            Debug.Assert(englishDto.PropertyName == "Empire State Building");

            Debug.Assert(arabicDto.CountryName == "الوِلايات المُتَّحِدة الأَمْريكيّة");
            Debug.Assert(arabicDto.LocationName == "نِيويورْك");
            Debug.Assert(arabicDto.PropertyName == "مبني المقاطعة الملكية");
        }
    }
}
```

I added a `Country` property to the `Location` class, to make sense of the model.
Though you *could* use `IMemberResolver`, you don't really need to (as shown in the sample code).