# How to dynamically map two class properties in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I have two applications A and B and there is another utility between them to map the object properties dynamically based on the client and then send requests to the destination. I have property mapping information in the `JSON` format.

For example, I have two clients.

**Client A** want to map `Employee` properties of **A** application with **B** Application like below:

**Application A Employee Class**           **Application B Employee Class**
`FirstName + LastName`   <--------->              `Name`
`Description`            <--------->              `Title`
`Title`                  <--------->              `JobTitle`

**Client B** want to map `Employee` properties of **A** application with **B** Application like below:

**Application A Employee Class**           **Application B Employee Class**
`FirstName + LastName`      <--------->          `Name`
`Description`               <--------->          `JobTitle`
`Title`                     <--------->          `Title`

I have some other fields which need to map based on the client's requirements.

How can I achieve this? so that I just get the mapping details from the database and map them accordingly

I tried automapper `ForMember` method but I don't know how to pass the value from database?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: Go more into detail what API means here. For example it could mean you need it to return a different Json, XML or you need a mapping to a client provided c# class or something else i didn't think of.

Comment: The first thing to think about is how you determine if it's client A or client B calling your API. Once you know that, you can pass a flag into the mapping resolver context, https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper. Then you can use the flag to pick the data source to map.

Comment: I have that info in my table

Comment: implement IMemberResolver for custom mapping - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63034642/automapper-based-on-dynamic-conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s set up the scene, assuming you have the info for the client (A or B) in the Employee records.

DB Entity,

```
Employee:
  FirstName,
  LastName
  Description,
  Title,
  ClientId
```

ViewModel,

```
EmployeeModel:
  Name,
  Title,
  JobTitle
```

Create custom resolvers,

```
public class TitleResolver : IValueResolver<Employee, EmployeeModel, string>
{
     public string Resolve(Employee source, EmployeeModel destination, string title, ResolutionContext context)
     {
        if(source.ClienId == "A") // as an example, you could do something different.
           return source.Description;
        return source.Title;
     }
}

 public class JobTitleResolver : IValueResolver<Employee, EmployeeModel, string>
 {
     public string Resolve(Employee source, EmployeeModel destination, string title, ResolutionContext context)
     {
        if(source.ClienId == "A")
           return source.Title;
        return source.Description;
     }
 }
```

When you configure the mapping,

```
 var configuration =new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeModel>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Title, opt => opt.MapFrom<TitleResolver>())
   .ForMember(dest => dest.JobTitle, opt => opt.MapFrom<JobTitleResolver>()));
```

Let me know if this makes sense.